# How to make multi account in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I'm confused to make user "student","teacher",and "admin" in laravel 5.2. I don't know steps after I type php artisan make:auth. Please tell me to use it untill route.php

Comment: zizaco entrust can do this for you.

Comment: Welcomes to SO , please follow [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),it will be easy to get your solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is laravel's authorization:

Have a look at [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization)

Or if you need extended functionality, have a look at [Cartalyst's Sentinel](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0). Which integrates very nicely with laravel

Comment: Huh, nifty. I hadn't noticed this yet.